# How can I use two ischanged's in the same formula?

Tags: formula, multi-select

```
AND(
ischanged (Services_Purchased__c),
ischanged (Services_Licensed__c),
NOT(OR(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client"),ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client - Group Contract"))), 
NOT(AND(ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c),ISBLANK(Services_Licensed__c))))
```

The two ischanged's here seem to cancel the rest of the formula out, whereas if I only use one ischanged for one of the fields, it works.

Comment: Hey please use , comma between both ischanged and please explain your scenario a bit briefly.

Comment: @pevan tej, is that better?

Comment: @ESil in your above formula both Serices_Purchased__c and Services_Licensed__c should be changed only then this formula will return true.(provided that other conditions are true) if you are able to save this formula everything should work fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @ESil looks like you are trying to say when either of them are changed. Please explain your test case

Comment: Please explain your use case properly.As per i understood you need validation to fire either either Services_Purchased__c or Services_Licensed__c is try to changed with other scenario in that case.please try to do like use OR like specified below. Please let me know if your use case is different OR(ischanged (Services_Purchased__c),ischanged (Services_Licensed__c)) @ESil

Comment: Thanks for the help, and apologies for the obscurity; I don't fully understand the ischanged function, so in turn, I didn't fully understand my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula will be triggered only if both `Services_Purchased__c` AND `Services_Licensed__c` fields have been changed when record is updated. If you need to check if *either* of the two fields have been changed use `OR`.

```
AND(
OR(ISCHANGED(Services_Purchased__c),ISCHANGED(Services_Licensed__c)),
NOT(OR(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client"),ISPICKVAL(Type, "Client - Group Contract"))), 
NOT(AND(ISBLANK(Services_Purchased__c),ISBLANK(Services_Licensed__c))))
```